# align contents to bottom of div without using position:absolute

Tags: html, css

hey there is there a way i can align the contents of a div tag to the bottom without using `position:absolute`. almost all other solutions on the internet uses `position:absolute` and/or `vertical-align:bottom`, but is there a way to do this without using `position:absolute` , let's say for example how do i align the cat in the image to the bottom of the div in this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Roy_S/FGL9H/) thanks!

the other solution i was thinking of was filling up the empty space at the top so that the image gets pushed down to the bottom but i also have no clue on how to do that either.

P.S. Please don't suggest using tables in the div, if that's possible.

Comment: Out of sheer personal curiosity, why wouldn't use use `position` (not necessarily absolute) or alignment?  Why say, "There are tools which exist, so let's use... something else!" What am I missing in the thinking here?

Comment: i don't have a issue using other position: but just not absolute. it makes the image position act like crazy when move elements are added

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thank you.  So that's the component which is really the annoyance.  I've always wondered about questions like this..  Thanks again.

Comment: Positioning can have it's advantages.  Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G6gcQ/2/) will help you in the long term.

Comment: i think i'll just lay down on the floor like that cat...

Comment: `position: absolute` can still work without `acting crazy` when more elements are added. It just depends on how and where you add them, all because once absoluted the item no longer takes up space in the document flow... http://jsfiddle.net/FGL9H/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
<div style="border:1px solid black; height:100px; display:table; width:100%;">

    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="height:90px;position:relative;display:block;" />
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox to solve this problem: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/FGL9H/1/)**

html

```
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="footerLike">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="height:90px;position:relative;display:inline-block;" />
</div>
```

css

```
.content {
    height:calc(100% - 102px); /* 100% - height of footer - borders */
}
.footerLike {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/FGL9H/2/)**, as said in comments

```
<div class="footerLike">
    <div class="dummy"><!-- you can put anything here --></div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="height:90px;position:relative;display:inline-block;" />
</div>


.footerLike {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100%;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.dummy {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: when i said filling the empty space up with something i was talking about the empty space inside the div that contains the image.